# Discord OAuth2 returns '{"error": "access_denied"}'

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, oauth-2.0, discord

I've currently walked into the world of OAuth2 and have *some* understanding of it. I'm attempting to make an application where you can authorise a Discord account and have it automatically invite you to a guild/server.

I am using an Express web server behind an Nginx proxy which is already configured and works like a charm. I use the Node.JS dependency called 'request' to make post requests to the Discord servers.

When I allow the application ([Discord Callback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8uCX.png)), the below code will handle the callback from Discord. The callback will contain a code in the **GET** query which will be forwarded to the Discord Token URL to receive an access token. This access token is what allows the application to do things to the users account, the thing is, it doesn't work which I will explain below. :-)

```
// there would be another variable here named 'state'
// which essentially is another security feature but this
// definitely works. The state gets calledback from the 
// discord authorisation which is a hashed cookie
var clientId = '123' // Discord client ID (string to not lose accuracy)
var clientSecret = 'secretsauce' // Discord secret key
var code = req.query.code // received on router event (express)
var discordTokenURL = 'https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token'
var redirectUri = 'https://myapp.com/callback/discord' // redirect for when I allow my app to look at my data, or even when I refuse it

// dependency to make request
var request = require('request')

// post the data to the discord server
request.post({
  url: discordTokenURL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  form: { grant_type: 'authorization_code', client_id: clientId, client_secret: clientSecret, code: code, redirect_uri: redirectUri }
},
  function (err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('server down or other error') // only errors when Discord server is down
    }
  res.send(body) // returns the server response ({"error": "access_denied"})
})
```

The code executes successfully without any errors. In the Discord OAuth2 docs, I am supposed to receive a response like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "6qrZcUqja7812RVdnEKjpzOL4CvHBFG",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 604800,
  "refresh_token": "D43f5y0ahjqew82jZ4NViEr2YafMKhue",
  "scope": "identify"
}
```

Unfortunately, I get a lovely one that looks like this:

```
{"error": "access_denied"}
```

Any help would be massivly appreciated, I've looked on so many articles and read the API docs so many times and nothing has been resolved. I've found out that if I set the 'grant_type' to 'client_credentials,' it does return a valid response which definitely confirms that my initial thought of my server being IP banned off Discord is incorrect. Unfortunately, 'client_credentials' does not serve my purpose, I need 'authorization_code.'

Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to make your own Discord OAuth application, just use passport and passport-discord to allow authorization to your application.

Passport makes it easy to create an authorization service, and is widely known. Here's the link to passport: http://passportjs.org/

Edit: Fixed link

Comment: Hi, I already have passport. It isn't suited for my purpose as I don't want them to be able to log onto my site with their Discord account. EDIT: Hang on, let me test this thing!

Comment: EDIT2: You're a legend, thanks for this! I would still like to know why my attempt didn't work, but thank you so much! Accepted answer. :)